# Wamp 2.4: php files not recognized

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to install a virtual host. Everything works fine except when I try to execute Php files. Those are downloaded like resources, not executed and rendered like HTML file (=> Chrome "download" the files like a resource (file)).

Note: I've already checked that there are no short open tags, only `<?php ... ?>`.
I've already tried to execute, successfully the concerned files in CLI like '`php -f MyFile.php`' and I'm stuck.

Thank you very much

Comment: What happens when you execute files in CLI? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works flawlessly.

Comment: May be a dumb question but how do you access your site in the browser? Do you go to `http://localhost/....`

Comment: Hi, I'm working with her. We've setup a virtualhost and we're accessing it through `http://webadresss.localhost.fr/...` (and the adress was added in the `hosts` file). So the base page ("`/`") is properly displayed, and all "pure" HTML files are properly displayed. It's only when accessing Php files. I've asked her to ask here because it's the first time I have such strange problem like this: all Php files are downloaded like resources files, instead of giving an HTML result

Comment: Even with a simple Php file like `<?php phpinfo();` it returns the file like a resource and it's downloaded...

Comment: Show your Virtual Hosts definition. It would seem likely you have done something in there that is causing this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your conf and make sure this is uncommented:

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/mod_php55.so
```

Then check to make sure you have this in your `<IfModule mime_module>` section:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

also make sure that you have it enabled by going to your wamp manager -> Apache -> Modules -> mime_module and that PHP is also enabled in your wamp manager.

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess file this line is uncomment so I comment it and now it works

## AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php